# Design of a Neural Network for Emotion Classification using Tweet Data

Tags: neural-network, sentiment-analysis, feature-extraction

I have a dataset of four emotion labelled tweets (anger, joy, fear, sadness). For instance, I transformed tweets to a vector similar to the following input vector for anger:

> Mean of frequency distribution to anger tokens
>
> `word2vec` similarity to anger
>
> Mean of anger in emotion lexicon
>
> Mean of anger in hashtag lexicon

Is that vector valid to train a neural network?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input vector looks fine to start with. Of-course, you might later make it much advanced with statistical and derivative data from twitter or other relevant APIs or datasets.

Your network has four outputs, just like you mentioned:

`Joy: [1,0,0,0]`
`Sadness: [0,1,0,0]`
`Fear: [0,0,1,0]`
`Anger: [0,0,0,1]`

And you may consider adding multiple hidden layers and make it a deep network, if you wish, to increase stability of your neural network prototype.

As your question also shows, it may be best to have a good preprocessor and feature extraction system, prior to training and testing your data, which it certainly seems you know, where the project is going.

Great project, best wishes, thank you for your good question and welcome to stackoverflow.com!

[image: An example architecture of a four-output ANN]

[Playground Tensorflow](https://playground.tensorflow.org/#activation=tanh&batchSize=16&dataset=xor&regDataset=reg-plane&learningRate=0.03&regularizationRate=0&noise=0&networkShape=8,4&seed=0.30095&showTestData=false&discretize=false&percTrainData=50&x=true&y=true&xTimesY=true&xSquared=true&ySquared=true&cosX=false&sinX=true&cosY=false&sinY=true&collectStats=false&problem=classification&initZero=false&hideText=false)

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer. Here is the challenge, when I built networks to test my feature vectors. one is multiple dense layers and other is two convolutional 1D network, I didn't satisfied with the results. that's made me doubt in the vector I suggested.

Comment: so if i got training vector looks like that 0.071428571 0.902887591 0.005818786 0.214285714 0 0.276094297 0.004706386 0.142857143 0.071428571 0.617585755 0.006649071 0.071428571 0 0.425330303 0.005618695 0.071428571
and the output is anger and joy so the output vector will be 1010, the network built was input layers, 12 dense first hidden layer, then 8 nodes in second hidden, then 4 the final output neurons. the training dataset 5000 the accuracy 48%, the testing dataset 1000 the accuracy 25%. batch 100 and 20 epochs, activation relu and output sigmoid